# bit.draw(stage, shiftOrigin) works on the Flash Player, but doesn't on the browser;

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a code here, that should save the stage to a file, but when I click the button that runs the function that has this code on the browser, it doesn't work. The window asking where to save is not shown.

```
private function cropAndSave():void
{
    var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
    var bit:BitmapData = new  BitmapData(bm.width, bm.height);

    var jpgEncoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(95);
    var shiftOrigin:Matrix = new Matrix();

    var now:Date = new Date();
    var outputFileName:String = now.getTime()+"_scrapeenet";

    outputFileName += ".jpg";

    shiftOrigin.translate(-bm.x,-bm.y);
    bit.draw(stage, shiftOrigin);

    file.save(jpgEncoder.encode(bit),outputFileName);
}
```

On Flash Player it works.
It also works if I change "stage" to some movieclip name for example. But I need to save all the stage and not just a movieclip.

This might be a bug.

Any way to solve?

Answer (score 1):

The AS3 reference docs say for flash.net.FileReference that:

> The FileReference.upload(), FileReference.download(), FileReference.load() and **FileReference.save()** functions are nonblocking. These functions return after they are called, before the file transmission is complete. In addition, **if the FileReference object goes out of scope, any transaction that is not yet completed on that object is canceled upon leaving the scope.** Be sure that your FileReference object remains in scope for as long as the upload, download, load or save is expected to continue.

It looks like your FileReference object goes out of scope immediately which may be automatically canceling your file save. Furthermore, the documentation states:

> In Flash Player, you can only call this method successfully in response to a user event (for example, in an event handler for a mouse click or keypress event). Otherwise, calling this method results in Flash Player throwing an Error exception.

Your pasted code does not show this action as a result of a MouseEvent or KeyboardEvent, so it's not clear right now whether you're acting based on user action.

Comment: Tnaks, but that is not problem. As I said. If I change this line  bit.draw(stage,shiftOrigin); to something like  bit.draw(somemovieclip,shiftOrigin); it saves the movieclip to the file. The problem just happens on the browsers.

Comment: Hmmmm Sorry, selective reading strikes again. I'm not sure what's up. The stage should be IBitmapDrawable. Have you tried wrapping a try/catch to see if there are runtime errors?

Comment: Problem solved. I installed the debugger version for IE and it shown what was wrong. It was some kind of security violation due the fact that I was loading swf's from another server.

Comment: Fantastic, glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: @valter you should answer your own question to mark it as solved.